# c++/OpenGL/GLSL, textures with "random" artifacts

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, artifacts

Would like to know if someone has experienced this and knows the reason. I'm getting these strange artifacts after using "texture arrays"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WUZR.png

(My gpu is AMD R9 270)

- **ninja edit** deleted the rest of the post for readability since it was just showing code where the problem could have been, since the project is open source now I only show the source of the problem(fragment shader)

Frag:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

uniform vec4 colour;
uniform vec2 light;

in DATA{
    vec4 position;
    vec2 uv;
    float tid;
    vec4 color;
}fs_in;

uniform sampler2D textures[32];

void main()
{
    float intensity = 1.0 / length(fs_in.position.xy - light);
    vec4 texColor = fs_in.color;
    if(fs_in.tid > 0.0){    
        int tid = int(fs_in.tid - 0.5);
        texColor = texture(textures[tid], fs_in.uv);
    }
    color = texColor; // * intensity;
}
```

Edit: github repos (sorry if It is missing some libs, having trouble linking them to github) https://github.com/PedDavid/NubDevEngineCpp

**Edit:** Credits to [derhass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327517/derhass) for pointing out I was doing something with undefined results (accessing the array without a constant ([tid])). I have it now working with

```
switch(tid){
    case 0: textureColor = texture(textures[0], fs_in.uv); break;
    ...
    case 31: textureColor = texture(textures[31], fs_in.uv); break;
}
```

Not the prettiest, but fine for now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm getting these strange artifacts after using "texture arrays"

You are not using "texture arrays". You use *arrays of texture samplers*. From your fragment shader:

> ```
> #version 330 core
> // ...
> in DATA{
>     // ...
>     float tid;
> }fs_in;
>
> //...
>
>     if(fs_in.tid > 0.0){    
>         int tid = int(fs_in.tid - 0.5);
>         texColor = texture(textures[tid], fs_in.uv);
>     }
> ```

What you try to do here is not allowed as per the [GLSL 3.30 specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.3.30.6.clean.pdf) which states

> Samplers aggregated into arrays within a shader (using square brackets
>   [ ]) can only be indexed with integral constant expressions (see
>   section 4.3.3 “Constant Expressions”).

Your `tid` is not a constant, so this will not work.

In GL 4, this constraint has been somewhat relaxed to (quote is from [GLSL 4.50 spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf)):

> When aggregated into arrays within a shader, samplers can only be
>   indexed with a dynamically uniform integral expression, otherwise
>   results are undefined.

Your now your input also isn't *dynamically uniform* either, so you will get undefined results too.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but maybe you can get it dobe by using [array textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture), which will represent a complete set of images as a single GL texture object and will not impose such constraints at accessing them.

Comment: I am still beginning, my code is mostly from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1x4hrdS97cI , it's working fine for him but thanks for the information so I can try an alternative

Comment: No artifacts now! You were completely right about the constant, managed to get it working by doing a "switch(tid){ case 0: textureColor = texture(textures[0], fs_in.uv); break; ...}"

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the shader is rendering whatever random data it finds in memory.
Have you tried checking that glBindTexture(...) is called at the right time (before render) and that the value used (as returned by glGenTextures(...)) is valid?

Comment: Both of them seem valid (glGenTextures returns 1, 2, 3 for the 3 textures and glBindTexture is binding 1, 2, 3 too and is only called on flushing). The artifacts seem to be always in the same place and they "come from other textures" (seem to be displaced, but debugging the shaders input outputing position as color seems to be perfect)